# Round Data that Includes Blanks

Tags: r

An example of a table I'm working with is as follows:

```
Column 1                      Column 2
300.82                          100.000000001
5578.76                         2000.98
932.00000000001                 6876.54
167                             -
900.01                          -
765.9999999999999995            -
100.00                          999.999999991
-                               8765.82
0.000001                        -
-                               67876.25
-                               25.67
5000.919999999                  900.93
760.84999999                    26.27
-                               11.97
100.98                          -
```

I have tried using `data <- round(data, 2)` but it gives me the error "non-numeric variable(s) in data frame."

I have tried including `na.rm=TRUE` but the round() function does not take a second parameter.

So, I'm unsure how to round the extreme (.00000001, .9999999995) type values without removing the `-` values.

Comment: Your data isn't numeric - if it were, missing values would be represented as `NA`. You need to convert your data to numeric. If it's a `character` class, you can go straight `as.numeric()`, but if it's a `factor` class use `as.numeric(as.character())`. (You'll have to do this to each column you want converted, either with a `loop` or an `lapply` or something that iterates over columns.)

Comment: @GregorThomas this should be an answer and so far is the best one because it explains why the error is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: @GregorThomas so are you saying, in general, I should never use ```-``` and rather just make them into NA's to help fix this in future cases?

Comment: @samrizz4 Yes, `-` is meaningless to R in this context. I've added an answr with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.

```
#Transform column data to numeric, this will set as NA all the "-"
#and round the numbers to the desired number of decimals
df$Column_1<-round(as.numeric(df$Column_1),2)

#Then substitute NA with "-"
df$Column_1[is.na(df$Column_1)]<-"-"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data isn't numeric - if it were, missing values would be represented as `NA` and your attempt to `round` would work just fine.

You need to convert your data to numeric. If it's a `character` class, you can go straight with `as.numeric()`, but if it's a `factor` class use `as.numeric(as.character())`. You'll have to do this to each column you want converted, either with a loop or an `lapply` or something that iterates over columns.  If you want to convert all your columns, you could do either of these:

```
data = lapply(data, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

library(dplyr)
data = mutate_all(data, ~as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

You should always make sure your data is the correct type. You can specify column classes when you import data, as well as customize what values should be treated as `NA` (check the documentation of whatever function you used to import the data, look for the `na.strings` in most functions, or the `na` argument in `readr` functions), you can check the column classes with, e.g., `str(data)` or `dplyr::glimpse(data)` or `sapply(data, class)` or looking at the "environment" tab in RStudio to make sure things are what they should be.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and explaining what I had mixed up!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `dplyr` method:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>%
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Column")), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, ~round(., 2))
```